# calling a function from another JavaScript file without eval()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a project that has two files with the same name, data.php and data.js. i am trying to run a function in data.js from list.js which is another file within the project.

The code below shows three different attempts i have tried and no of them work. The first throws an error saying no function for conditionTemplate in data.php. the other two throw the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'condtionTemplate' of undefined.

**list.js**

```
if (this.filter == "correct") {
    window["condtionTemplate"](true);
    window["data"]["condtionTemplate"](true);
    window["data.js"]["condtionTemplate"](true);
}
```

This is the function i am trying to get to inside data.js

**data.js**

```
list = new listFiler();
list.prototype.condtionTemplate = function(status) {
    if (status) {
        main_buttons.enabled("next", false);
    } else {
        main_buttons.enabled("back", true);
    }
}
```

**data.php**

```
<body>    
    <script src="javascript/list.js?1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/data.js?1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you load somewhere data.js?

Comment: what is `list`? the type, not the file.

Comment: @thomas updated the question. `listFilter` is where the first code block is

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, inside data.php

Comment: please add the relvant parts of data.php, data.js and list.js

Comment: ??? so `list` is a function? Actually, I doubt it, but telling by your code, it has to be. As Nina said, please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the load order to

```
<script src="javascript/data.js?1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/list.js?1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add a prototype to the function `listFiler`.

```
listFiler.prototype.condtionTemplate = function(status) {
    if (status) {
        main_buttons.enabled("next", false);
    } else {
        main_buttons.enabled("back", true);
    }
};
```

Use an instance

```
var list = new listFiler();
```

with condtionTemplate.

```
if (this.filter == "correct") { 
    list.condtionTemplate(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i think i was trying to over complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<script src="data.js" />
<script src="list.js" />
<script>
   condtionTemplate() ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this would work however not in this scenario. i need to run conditionTemplate this from the list.js file.

Comment: There is no way to do that then, sorry.

Comment: it works if i use eval(), however from research this is not good practise